# UItableview header flicker when we reuse the cell Identifier

Tags: iphone

I have created a cell using

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetListUserName";

CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease] ;
}
```

and used the following code to set up a section header:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        UIView* customView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, -4.0, 320.0, 67.0)]autorelease];
        [customView setOpaque:YES];
        UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-2.0, -4.0, 328.0, 67.0)];
        [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header-msg.png"]];
        [image setOpaque:YES];
        [customView addSubview:image];

        UILabel *label1 =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 100, 12)];
        label1.text =@"TWEETS MATCHING:"; 
        label1.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
        [label1 setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [label1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:9]];;
        [label1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [customView addSubview:label1];
        [label1 release];

        UILabel *label2 =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 6, 315, 50)];
        label2.text =usernametag; 
        label2.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
        [label2 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [label2 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20]];
        [label2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [customView addSubview:label2];
        [label2 release];


        return customView;

    }
```

However, when I quickly scroll the table the header flickers in almost all cases. How can I prevent this flickering?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you need to test if it is already set. The way you have it now it will run the above code each time you scroll, meaning it will get set quite a lot.

Comment: actually not mentioned in the code but I am releasing custom view

Comment: This is not the cause of the header for that cell flickering.  I know this is an old question...but it is now happening to me.

Comment: Are you calling [tableView reloadData] anywhere that gets called repeatedly?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue.

In my case the reason was within the custom table cell. 
Within my custom table cell I used a`UITextView` oject with its `scrollEnabled` property set to **`NO`** and the `editable` property set to **`NO`**.

The probelm was linked to scrollEnabled=NO. With scrollEnabled=YES I hat no issues.

However, as a `UITextView` without editing and scrolling is not much different from a `UILabel`, I replaced the `UITextView` with a `UILabel` setting `numberOfLines` to 0.

Don't ask me why. It somply worked that way. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are changing the frame of the header in layoutsubviews. If you remove that, it will be fixed.